# Create list from for loop

Tags: python

this is my code so far

```
print("L = ",[4,10,4,2,9,5,4])

Startlist = [4,10,4,2,9,5,4]
usrinput = int(input("Enter an element to search for in the list: "))
for i in [i for i,x in enumerate(Startlist) if x == usrinput]:
    print(i)
```

I'm trying to however make a new list from the for loops printed numbers.This is the sample run i got by entering 4

```
L =  [4, 10, 4, 2, 9, 5, 4]
Enter an element to search for in the list: 4
0
2
6
```

how could i turn the 0 2 6 into [0,2,6]?

Thanks for any responses

Comment: You already have the list here: `[i for i,x in enumerate(Startlist) if x == usrinput]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already made the list!  The heavy lifting in your code is in the temporary array you created and iterated over.

```
 newlist = [i for i,x in enumerate(Startlist) if x == usrinput]
```

Comment: thanks! yeah i clearly was following traditional for loop structure too much to notice there was no need to print(i) separately

Answer (score 3):

Just print the list comprehension:

```
print([i for i,x in enumerate(Startlist) if x == usrinput])
```

Comment: @user2840144 You should probably accept one of these answers, by clicking the tick mark next to the one you like.